# Event Viewer — log to sub folder?

Tags: c#, windows-services, event-log

I've searched and searched and can't find the answer.  We have a custom service that runs and logs into the Event Viewer.  In Windows 7, there's a folder called "Applications and Services Logs".  How do I log an event in there?  Is it even possible?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220837/understanding-how-trace-works-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will happen automatically when you create a new Event Log using something like:

```
EventLog.CreateEventSource("Our Source", "Our Log");
```

**And** that call requires elevated privileges, but only needs to be done once. After that, you can reference with normal privileges using.

```
EventLog _eventLog = new EventLog("Our Log"); // Writes to OUR event log--NOT the system created "Application"
```

Note: If you are moving your source from `Application` to your custom log, it may need some tweaking and/or a reboot as it is not normal to move a source from one log to another.

If you are using InstalUtil, you can also create the log using a `System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller`

Comment: Thank You Jim.  I created a simple console application and confirmed it worked.  Can't figure out why I made it more difficult than it should be.